# Java Breakout game bouncing the ball

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine, breakout

I'm trying to make a breakout game in java. The ball bounces when hit to stones and bat but it won't after hitting the walls. See this paste for what I use.

http://pastebin.com/pkGsCBMa

Could anybody spot the error in the code...

Thanks

EDIT: when printing out the velocities, I get this output.

```
vx 0.0     vy  0.0
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.0     vy  0.0
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
vx 0.02    vy -0.02
```

### Edit

This is the solution. I had changed the bounce() method to this.

```
/**
 * This object bounces back from the other object in a natural way. Please
 * realize that the bounce is not completely accurate because this depends
 * on many properties. But in many situations the effect is good enough. Had
 * some bugs in pixel perfect detection mode if the image has a larger area
 * of complete alpha. If using PPCD, make the object fit the image size by
 * removing the alpha and resizing the image.
 */
public void bounce(GObject other){
    int xd = (int) ((other.x + other.getWidth() / 2) - (x + getWidth() / 2));
    int yd = (int) ((other.y + other.getHeight() / 2) - (y + getHeight() / 2));
    if (xd < 0) {
        xd = -xd;
    }
    if (yd < 0) {
        yd = -yd;
    }
    if (xd > yd) {
        dx = -dx;
    } else {
        dy = -dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say it doesn't bounce on the wall do you mean that it just goes off the screen or stops?

Comment: @SeanF It just stops. The blocks are solid objects

Answer (score 4):

A common cause of this problem is that the colliding objects are overlapping and get stuck in a state of continuous collisions.

So the ball is moving relatively quickly and collides with a block. However since the simulation is discrete, the ball actually goes **into** the block a little bit. You then correctly detect a collision and reverse the velocity. However on the next update cycle, for whatever reason, the ball might still be inside the block. Thus the program detects another "collision" and reverses the velocity again.

The result is that your ball jitters around the edge of the block, constantly reversing velocities.

Comment: But I was aligning the ball with the blocks. See the bounce(GObject) method

Comment: To debug this problem, I suggest printing out the velocity of the ball in the update step.

Answer (score 3):

in the `bounce` function, the `if` and `else if` don't cover every value., i suggest you replace `>` with `>=` or the `<` with `<=`.

Comment: I am using < and > because if the value is zero, then reversing the velocities is a useless thing to do.